# Dual boot ubuntu 12.10 and windows 8 Dell Inspiron 15 r

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, dell, windows-8

I purchased a new Dell 15R laptop which came with pre installed windows 8 64 bit and ueifi boot. I made a ubuntu 12.10 dvd and loaded it. When i started installing my installer could not recognise any other windows 8  or any other OS installed. When i moved to advanced partition tool, i could see my free space, my windows partitions. But i did not proceed. can anyone help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with my Dell XPS 8500 desktop. I found the following bug report helpful:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1079056

The workaround suggested there worked for me. Run ubiquity (the Ubuntu installer) with the following command:

`$ WINOSDATA=true ubiquity`

Slightly more detailed instructions, if they are needed:

1. Boot your computer from the Ubuntu Live CD (or USB), and select the
   option "Try Ubuntu without installing".
2. Open a terminal window, e.g. by pressing Ctrl+ALt+T.
3. Enter the command `$ WINOSDATA=true ubiquity`

The Ubuntu installer should then detect your Windows 8 installation (it did for me).

The problem appears to be with os-prober, the command used by ubiquity to detect installed operating systems. You can test this by running first `$ sudo os-prober`, and then `$ sudo WINOSDATA=true os-prober`. You may find that in the first case, no OS is detected, but in the second, Windows 8 is detected. (Substituting any non-zero value for "true" works equally well. Don't ask me why.)

Comment: This worked perfectly in my case - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go to the boot options when the machine starts and disable the UEFI!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my laptop that came with Windows 8.  It turned out there were both GPT and MBR partition tables, which was confusing the installed (and gparted).  Follow these steps:

Boot Live CD, don't choose the install option, choose test out Ubuntu.

Open a shell and type

```sh
sudo sgdisk --zap /dev/sda
```

Where sda is the disk with the Windows partition. It'll complain about partition problems, but this is ok.

Proceed with your Ubuntu installation.

[source here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604074&page=4&p=10022223#post10022223)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.