# Why doesn't Ubuntu 12.04 recognize my Windows 7 partition?

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, windows-7

After some problems trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, now I have Windows 7 installed and it works just fine. But when I am going to install Ubuntu it doesn't recognize my windows.

What should I do to see Ubuntu in my PC? My Ubuntu version is 12.04 64 bit.

PC specs:

```
Asus crosshair IV formula 
AMD phenom II x6 1055t @ 4.1GHz
Corsiar 4x2Gb 1766 @ 9-9-9-24
AMD Radeon 7870 GHz edition
WD 1TB caviar black
```

Comment: what do you mean `it doesn't recognize my windows`?

Comment: After boot when ubuntu coming up it says you don't have any OS installed on your system while i have windows 7 ,so there is no option like install ubuntu along side windows 7 !!

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't care if you have any other operating systems installed, can you provide a picture?

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause of the "missing partitions" problem is one of two things:

- **A damaged partition table** -- On an MBR disk, my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program can usually fix such problems. See the FixParts page for details on how to use it. It's usually just a matter of launching the program on the disk, typing `p` to verify that it's detected your partitions correctly, and then typing `w` to save the fixes.
- **Leftover motherboard-based software RAID data** -- This can usually be fixed by typing `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda`, IIRC, changing the device filename as necessary. You may also need to go into your firmware setup to disable RAID. Of course, if you're actually using RAID you should *not* do this!

Answer (score 0):

It might be there, just not showing up yet in Nautilus. Try mounting the drive.

- In terminal:
- `sudo blkid`  - ( get the uuid of the drive)
- `sudo mkdir /media/<mount point>` << create the mount point, media is default
- `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
- [Proper fstab entry to mount a samba share on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot)

> UUID=Put_UUID_Here /media/win ntfs
>   rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0

Comment: I fail to see how the samba share part is relevant, they're not trying to mount a share.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu, choose the `Something Else` option. (on the bottom of the screenshot below)

[image]

This will show your Windows partitions, and allow you to install Ubuntu on other partitions.
See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall#Installation_type

Answer (score -1):

You say: "when I am going to install Ubuntu it doesn't recognize my windows". This suggests to me that your problem is similar to the one described, for example, in this question:
[Dual boot ubuntu 12.10 and windows 8 Dell Inspiron 15 r](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255939/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-and-windows-8-dell-inspiron-15-r)

If so, the answers to that question may be helpful.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with my laptop that originally have Windows 8 (using GPT) that I installed Windows 7 (using MBR) on.  I found the solution here...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604074&page=4&p=10022223#post10022223

After so much time messing around with Windows, Ubuntu feels great!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.