# Ubuntu 12.04 can't see Windows 7

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, system-installation

I already read other questions like this but nothing seems to work.
I just had my ASUS UX31A recovered from factory with Windows 7. Everything is fine there, so I tried to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (the first time installation worked fine, so I was confident it would have worked this time as well). I shrik volume from my second Windows partition to make it unallocated, boot the Ubuntu live USB and when I try to install it tells me that there's no other operating sistem to install Ubuntu alongside. If I proceed with the manual operation to create the swap area and the OS partition, it doesn't make me choose whether it should be logical or principal, so I don't dare to go on.
If I look at GParted it doesn't show the label OS on C:, while on the disk manager in Windows everything seems ok.
What should I do? I DO NOT want to reinstall Windows, any other clue?
Thanks

**EDIT 1**
I tried to launch `os-prober` in my Terminal and the only option I get is

```
/dev/sda5:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows1:chain
```

while Windows 7 (mounted on dev/sda3) is not showed.

This is what I see in my Disk Manager inside Windows 7:

[image: screenshot 1]]

<sub>Click for a full-resolution image.</sub>

(Sorry for the Italian Language, C: basically is the partition with Windows system's file, while the D: one is for data), while this is what I see when I launch GParted:

[image: screenshot 2]

<sub>Click for a full-resolution image.</sub>

Comment: Which questions have you looked at, and what have you tried, specifically?

Comment: [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265132/why-doesnt-ubuntu-12-04-recognize-my-windows-7-partition) , I was looking for informations about FixParts but for someone it ended up in an unbootable system, so I let it go

Comment: Have you looked at this one ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/141656/

Comment: wow that topic sure is a mess! I did't see that before, reading through it I got that the winning move is to use the os-prober / dmraid thing, right?

Comment: I think so.  I agree about the mess ; it looks like we need to make an effort to consolidate the good parts of those similar questions.

Comment: os-prober only shows the Windows Recovery environment partition (/dev/sda5). Windows 7 is installed on sda3