# Lubuntu 13.10 Installer does not detect Windows 7 or any partitions & black screen during install

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu, unetbootin

I know this question has been asked numerous times and has been answered;

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604074&page=4&p=10022223#post10022223

[Why doesn't Ubuntu 12.04 recognize my Windows 7 partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265132/why-doesnt-ubuntu-12-04-recognize-my-windows-7-partition)

(these are just a couple of the articles/threads I have read) however none of the solutions provided seem to solve my problem.

I have a Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite with a 128GB SSD with Windows 7 64-bit installed. I created an unformatted partition where I intended to install Lubuntu to.

I then created a USB boot disk using unetbootin, now when I boot to this and hit 'install Lubuntu' the Lubuntu splash screen appears and then the screen simply goes blank. I got round this by changing the settings to 'nomodeset' which then take me to the standard Lubuntu install/setup. However the installer does not detect my windows 7 OS or the partition I created and sees the SSD as just one partition.

I have tried clearing any RAID data - I have read that this can cause issues, and tried using sgdisk/gdisk to 'zap' the partition however the installer still cannot see windows 7 or the partition.

The strange thing is I used the exact same USB to install to my PC which had no problem with a black screen or detecting my windows 7 installation. The only difference being that I have multiple HDD so installed Lubuntu to a HDD of its own (no partition nonsense - except for the swap area).

Any help you guys can give me would be appreciated as I am out of ideas.

Thanks

QP

Comment: Please boot a Linux emergency disk and run `sudo parted /dev/sda print`, `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`, and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` (and repeat these for `/dev/sdb` and any other disks you have). Note that you'll probably need to install the `gdisk` package to run the `gdisk` command. Edit your question to show the output of these commands. Without this output, any answer is a guess.

Answer (score 0):

check to see if you have damage in file-system you use FAT32/NTFS, i had the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I re-formatted the partition a few times just in case but I will check for any damage properly.

Comment: No good I'm afraid, still have the problem!